# Sharing one r420 Rfid reader on the same network

Tags: rfid

I just have a question that two client PC can connect the same rfid reader R40 impinj at the same time? Eg Pc A is using Atena 1 data, Pc B is using antena 2 data. just only one Rfid reader.

I can not solve problem, i only want to get rfid data from each atena to each corresponding Pc

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible to do out of the box with the Impinj R420. That reader uses Low Level Reader Protocol (LLRP) which only allows one active connection at a time.

You can go around this by creating a sort of a "middle ware" where one of the PC connects to the reader, receives all the tags reads and forwards tags read on antenna 2 to the second PC.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with or write your own  REST middleware Take a look at the Impinj Reader Configuration REST API.  You can easily have multiple PC's receive data from an atomic reader  without needing to connect to the actual RFID device.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, only one active connection is allowed at any moment in time. The only way to achieve this is writing your own middle-ware, depending how complex is your business logic, it could be easy or hard to achieve, also you could do is an onboard application, to run inside the reader, it is a more complex approach, and the easiest way to achieve this is to use the reader Impinj R700 (in case you could change the reader), it allows multiple active connections (max 5) using the reader IOT device interface.